# Eliminate render-blocking CSS without using JavaScript - GoogleAMP

Tags: css, amp-html, render-blocking

I have scenario in `GoogleAMP` Project, where I can not move `CSS` out of head tag. Or event can't create element with `JavaScript`. And add it to head later after page content loads.

[image]

Is there another way so it may satisfy AMP restrictions as well as GooglePageSpeed insights.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi you just described the nature of AMP. Please explain what exactly you want to do? Be specific. I understand it is regarding fetching dynamic style.

Comment: I basically want to avoid this render blocking.
A solution is normally; to write the css files for font awesome at the end of body tag, but AMP doesn't allow to write css files out of head.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your css using link property whitelisted by AMP

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css">
```

The following origins are whitelisted and allowed for font serving via link tags:

Typography.com: https://cloud.typography.com

Fonts.com: https://fast.fonts.net

Google Fonts: https://fonts.googleapis.com

Typekit: https://use.typekit.net

Font Awesome: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com, https://use.fontawesome.com

[For more information click here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/design/responsive/custom_fonts)

**Update :** for GooglePageSpeed insights (render-blocking) css

you can use like this

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900" rel="preload" as="style">
```

**Note :** preload work with modern browser only

Comment: I am using google Fonts (whitelisted origin) But still the issues is there.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zayantravel.com%2F.

Comment: @Mutafaf check my updated answer, hope this help you. also please validate your your site with amp there are some errors.

Comment: This would create another issue as you mentioned, in your Note.

Comment: @Mutafaf it isn't create the issue, some old version of browser does not support

Answer (score 0):

Okay as far as I know there is no way of fetching 3rd party css to AMP page. But you can download fontawesome's `all.css` file and manually copy the styles from it to your `<style amp-custom>` tag. Again since AMP does not permit style more than `50 KB` you will have to handpick the necessary styles from fontawesome.

PS: I'm not sure if there is any copyright issue in using fontawesome styles as described above, please do check that. But it is guaranteed to work.

Comment: This was just an example question.
What if i need to use google fonts 

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

So I will have to do the same? 
I don't think its a good decision to copy all the css in <style amp-custom>.
I hope there would be some better solution.